What virtual memory areas are randomized exactly and under which circunstances?
In a Red Hat machine of ours, with /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space at 2, I have been inspecting the memory layout of our process trying to understand in a fine-grained detail how memory is allocated etc, and something caught my attention:
       ADDR  PERM        VM       RSS      SWAP  LAZYFREE  VMFLAGS                  MAPPING
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                     3.13G     2.33G   353.91M        0K                           {TOTALS}                  │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│     4.00M  r-xp     7.48M     1.14M        0K        0K  rd ex mr mw me dw sd     OurBinary                 │
│-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------│
│    11.48M           7.48M     1.14M        0K        0K                                                     │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│    13.48M  r--p        4K        4K        0K        0K  rd mr mw me dw ac sd     OurBinary                 │
│            rw-p       24K       12K        0K        0K  rd wr mr mw me dw ac sd  OurBinary                 │
│            rw-p     5.20M        8K       20K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------│
│    18.71M           5.22M       24K       20K        0K                                                     │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│    21.36M  rw-p     2.56G     2.26G   309.06M        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd     [heap]                    │
│-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------│
│     2.58G           2.56G     2.26G   309.06M        0K                                                     │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│   127.14T  rw-p    45.78M    28.01M    17.77M        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│            rw-p      132K       20K        0K        0K  rd wr mr mw me nr sd                               │
│            ---p    63.87M        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me nr sd                                     │
│            rw-p      132K        0K        8K        0K  rd wr mr mw me nr sd                               │
│            ---p    63.87M        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me nr sd                                     │
│            rw-p     1.23M      208K      748K        0K  rd wr mr mw me nr sd                               │
│            ---p    62.77M        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me nr sd                                     │
│            rw-p      132K       32K        0K        0K  rd wr mr mw me nr sd                               │
│            ---p    63.87M        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me nr sd                                     │
│            rw-p      132K        0K        8K        0K  rd wr mr mw me nr sd                               │
│            ---p    63.87M        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me nr sd                                     │
│-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------│
│   127.14T         365.78M    28.27M    18.52M        0K                                                     │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│   127.14T  rw-p    15.42M    10.07M       68K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│            r-xp       12K        8K        0K        0K  rd ex mr mw me sd        libnque19.so              │
│            ---p     2.00M        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd              libnque19.so              │
│            r--p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd mr mw me ac sd        libnque19.so              │
│            rw-p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd     libnque19.so              │
│            r-xp       44K       40K        0K        0K  rd ex mr mw me sd        libnuma.so.1.0.0          │
│            ---p     2.00M        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd              libnuma.so.1.0.0          │
│            r--p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd mr mw me ac sd        libnuma.so.1.0.0          │
│            rw-p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd     libnuma.so.1.0.0          │
│            r--p      772K       64K        0K        0K  rd mr mw me nr sd        timezlrg_32.dat           │
│            ---p        4K        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd                                        │
│            rw-p     8.00M        0K       56K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│            ---p        4K        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd                                        │
│            rw-p     8.48M      372K       84K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│            r-xp       44K       44K        0K        0K  rd ex mr mw me sd        libnss_files-2.28.so      │
│            ---p     2.00M        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd              libnss_files-2.28.so      │
│            r--p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd mr mw me ac sd        libnss_files-2.28.so      │
│            rw-p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd     libnss_files-2.28.so      │
│            rw-p       24K        0K        0K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│            ---p        4K        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd                                        │
│            rw-p     8.00M       20K       40K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│            ---p        4K        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd                                        │
│            rw-p     8.00M        0K       60K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│            ---p        4K        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd                                        │
│            rw-p    46.64M    15.05M    23.65M        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│            r-xp     4.85M     2.66M        0K        0K  rd ex mr mw me sd        libnnz19.so               │
│            ---p     2.00M        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd              libnnz19.so               │
│            r--p      184K        0K      184K        0K  rd mr mw me ac sd        libnnz19.so               │
│            rw-p      252K       40K       92K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd     libnnz19.so               │
│            rw-p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│            r-xp     1.80M     1.58M        0K        0K  rd ex mr mw me sd        libc-2.28.so              │
│            ---p     2.00M        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd              libc-2.28.so              │
│            r--p       16K       12K        4K        0K  rd mr mw me ac sd        libc-2.28.so              │
│            rw-p        8K        8K        0K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd     libc-2.28.so              │
│            rw-p       16K       12K        4K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│            r-xp       92K       88K        0K        0K  rd ex mr mw me sd        libgcc_s-8-20210514.so.1  │
│            ---p     2.00M        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd              libgcc_s-8-20210514.so.1  │
│            r--p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd mr mw me ac sd        libgcc_s-8-20210514.so.1  │
│            rw-p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd     libgcc_s-8-20210514.so.1  │
│            r-xp     1.52M     1.18M        0K        0K  rd ex mr mw me sd        libstdc++.so.6.0.25       │
│            ---p     2.00M        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd              libstdc++.so.6.0.25       │
│            r--p       48K        4K       44K        0K  rd mr mw me ac sd        libstdc++.so.6.0.25       │
│            rw-p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd     libstdc++.so.6.0.25       │
│            rw-p       12K        0K       12K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│            r-xp     1.50M      312K        0K        0K  rd ex mr mw me sd        libm-2.28.so              │
│            ---p     2.00M        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd              libm-2.28.so              │
│            r--p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd mr mw me ac sd        libm-2.28.so              │
│            rw-p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd     libm-2.28.so              │
│            r-xp       80K       60K        0K        0K  rd ex mr mw me sd        libresolv-2.28.so         │
│            ---p     2.00M        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd              libresolv-2.28.so         │
│            r--p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd mr mw me ac sd        libresolv-2.28.so         │
│            rw-p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd     libresolv-2.28.so         │
│            rw-p        8K        0K        0K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│            r-xp        8K        8K        0K        0K  rd ex mr mw me sd        libaio.so.1.0.1           │
│            ---p     2.00M        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd              libaio.so.1.0.1           │
│            r--p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd mr mw me ac sd        libaio.so.1.0.1           │
│            rw-p        4K        0K        0K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│            r-xp       28K       28K        0K        0K  rd ex mr mw me sd        librt-2.28.so             │
│            ---p     2.00M        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd              librt-2.28.so             │
│            r--p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd mr mw me ac sd        librt-2.28.so             │
│            rw-p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd     librt-2.28.so             │
│            r-xp       88K       64K        0K        0K  rd ex mr mw me sd        libnsl-2.28.so            │
│            ---p     2.00M        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd              libnsl-2.28.so            │
│            r--p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd mr mw me ac sd        libnsl-2.28.so            │
│            rw-p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd     libnsl-2.28.so            │
│            rw-p        8K        0K        0K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│            r-xp      108K       88K        0K        0K  rd ex mr mw me sd        libpthread-2.28.so        │
│            ---p     2.00M        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd              libpthread-2.28.so        │
│            r--p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd mr mw me ac sd        libpthread-2.28.so        │
│            rw-p        4K        4K        0K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd     libpthread-2.28.so        │
│            rw-p       16K        4K        0K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│            r-xp       12K       12K        0K        0K  rd ex mr mw me sd        libdl-2.28.so             │
│            ---p     2.00M        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd              libdl-2.28.so             │
│            r--p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd mr mw me ac sd        libdl-2.28.so             │
│            rw-p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd     libdl-2.28.so             │
│            r-xp     3.52M     1.76M        0K        0K  rd ex mr mw me sd        libclntshcore.so.19.1     │
│            ---p     2.00M        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd              libclntshcore.so.19.1     │
│            r--p       24K        0K       24K        0K  rd mr mw me ac sd        libclntshcore.so.19.1     │
│            rw-p       20K        0K       20K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd     libclntshcore.so.19.1     │
│            rw-p       64K        0K       52K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│            r-xp    60.16M    11.69M        0K        0K  rd ex mr mw me sd        libclntsh.so.19.1         │
│            ---p     2.00M        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd              libclntsh.so.19.1         │
│            r--p     1.44M        0K     1.42M        0K  rd mr mw me ac sd        libclntsh.so.19.1         │
│            rw-p      264K        4K      188K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd     libclntsh.so.19.1         │
│            rw-p      156K        4K       36K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│            r-xp      188K      188K        0K        0K  rd ex mr mw me dw sd     ld-2.28.so                │
│-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------│
│   127.14T         203.95M    45.44M    26.10M        0K                                                     │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│   127.14T  ---p        4K        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd                                        │
│            rw-p      760K      412K      112K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│            r--p       96K       92K        0K        0K  rd mr mw me sd           libtibrv.so               │
│            r-xp      316K       64K        0K        0K  rd ex mr mw me sd        libtibrv.so               │
│            r--p      108K        0K        0K        0K  rd mr mw me sd           libtibrv.so               │
│            r--p        4K        0K        4K        0K  rd mr mw me ac sd        libtibrv.so               │
│            rw-p       16K        0K       16K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd     libtibrv.so               │
│            rw-p       12K        0K        8K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------│
│   127.14T           1.29M      568K      140K        0K                                                     │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│   127.14T  rw-p        8K        0K        8K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│            r--p       96K       92K        0K        0K  rd mr mw me sd           libtibrv64.so             │
│            r-xp      316K      316K        0K        0K  rd ex mr mw me sd        libtibrv64.so             │
│            r--p      108K       64K        0K        0K  rd mr mw me sd           libtibrv64.so             │
│            r--p        4K        4K        0K        0K  rd mr mw me ac sd        libtibrv64.so             │
│            rw-p       16K       16K        0K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd     libtibrv64.so             │
│            rw-p        4K        4K        0K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│            r--p       28K       28K        0K        0K  rd mr mw me sd           libtibrvcm64.so           │
│            r-xp       72K       72K        0K        0K  rd ex mr mw me sd        libtibrvcm64.so           │
│            r--p       16K       16K        0K        0K  rd mr mw me sd           libtibrvcm64.so           │
│            ---p        4K        0K        0K        0K  mr mw me sd              libtibrvcm64.so           │
│            r--p        4K        4K        0K        0K  rd mr mw me ac sd        libtibrvcm64.so           │
│            rw-p        4K        4K        0K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd     libtibrvcm64.so           │
│            rw-p        8K        4K        4K        0K  rd wr mr mw me ac sd                               │
│            r--p        4K        4K        0K        0K  rd mr mw me dw ac sd     ld-2.28.so                │
│            rw-p        8K        8K        0K        0K  rd wr mr mw me dw ac sd  ld-2.28.so                │
│-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------│
│   127.14T            700K      636K       12K        0K                                                     │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│   127.99T  rw-p      136K       36K       76K        0K  rd wr mr mw me gd ac     [stack]                   │
│-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------│
│   127.99T            136K       36K       76K        0K                                                     │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│   127.99T  r--p       16K        0K        0K        0K  rd mr pf io de dd sd     [vvar]                    │
│            r-xp        8K        4K        0K        0K  rd ex mr mw me de sd     [vdso]                    │
│-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------│
│   127.99T             24K        4K        0K        0K                                                     │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│    16.00E  r-xp        4K        0K        0K        0K  rd ex                    [vsyscall]                │
│-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------│
│    16.00E              4K        0K        0K        0K                                                     │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

These boxes comes from a script of mine that explores VMAs of a process, locates contiguous regions of memory, and draw boxes around them (and also shows the ADDR in an human readable form to get a sense of the gaps between regions).
I know that the binary always starts at the 4MB boundaries, so the starting address of the binary is not randomized, that the [heap] is randomized inside the end of the binary map and the next 8MB, and the [stack] is also randomized.
But besides that, what else is randomized? You can see that all the malloc subheaps of the different threads are one after the other, and also that all the libraries comes one after the other in contiguous regions as well, but sometimes there's gaps between library mappings as well.
However, in some other processes, I have observed malloc subheaps inside regions that are mostly dominated by library mappings.
So, which is the "algorithm" that the kernel follow to decide what to randomize and what not (except VSDO, [stack] and [heap] which is explicitly documented as randomized)? Also, why is the starting address of the binary itself not randomized either? It makes sense to protect it from attacks as well isn't?

when you run the same program again, do you get the same mappings?

@MarcusMüller Not neccesarily, but the fact that a lot of allocations are contiguous is a constant in all of our processes. Surely, not all calls to mmap are randomized, and there's a strong preference for contiguous VMAs.
